# Does Dart have extension methods like c#?

Tags: extension-methods, dart

Can you can make extension methods in dart? like you can in C# e.g.:

```
void swap(this CssClassSet ccs, String oldClass, String newClass)
{
    ccs.remove(oldClass);
    ccs.add(newClass);
}
```

is this sort of thing possible with Dart? I would like to extend CssClassSet to have a `swap(String oldClass, String newClass)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet. See [issue 9991 - scoped object extensions](http://dartbug.com/9991).

Comment: `Rejected` in this case, it would be unwise. This reduces the appeal. `Accepted` in this case does not mean anything. Read Gilad Bracha comments at this issue [Add C#-style extension methods](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13).

Comment: There's been an update and the discussion is now moved [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/177)

Answer (score 7):

6 years later and extension functions are finally on the horizon:
https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/41#issuecomment-539251446

They will be included in dart 2.6

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was [introduced in Dart `2.6`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58288235/6509751).

The syntax is the following:

```dart
extension YourExtension on YourClass {
  void yourFunction() {
    this.anyMember(); // You can access `anyMember` of `YourClass` using `this`.
    anyMember(); // You can access `anyMember` of `YourClass` without `this`.
  }
}

void main() {
  YourClass yourVariable;

  yourVariable.yourFunction(); // valid
}
```

You can also extend types like `int`:

```dart
void main() {
  5.fancyPrint();
  3.minusThree; // returns 0
}

extension FancyInt on int {
  void fancyPrint() => print('The magic number is $this.');

  int get minusThree => this - 3;
}
```

You can [learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751).