# How do I use Dart extension functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart 2.6 introduces a new language feature called "**[static extension members](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.6/static-extension-members/feature-specification.md)**".
However, I do not quite understand how to use it.

I would like to easily get the `childCount` of a `Row` or `Column`, i.e. use `row.childCount` instead of `row.children.length`:

```dart
void main() {
  final row = Row(children: const [Text('one'), Text('two')]), 
      column = Column(children: const [Text('one'), Text('two'), Text('three')]);

  print(row.childCount); // Should print "2".

  print(column.childCount); // Should print "3".
}
```

I tried to do the following, but it is a syntax error:

```dart
Row.childCount() => this.children.length;

Column.childCount() => this.children.length;
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There is an [official video by the Flutter team](https://youtu.be/D3j0OSfT9ZI) about extension methods now.

### Static extension members

Here is an intuitive example of how extension methods work:

```dart
extension FancyNum on num {
  num plus(num other) => this + other;

  num times(num other) => this * other;
}
```

I simply extend `num` here and add methods to the class. This could be used like this:

```dart
print(5.plus(3)); // Equal to "5 + 3".
print(5.times(8)); // Equal to "5 * 8".
print(2.plus(1).times(3)); // Equal to "(2 + 1) * 3".
```

Note that the name `FancyNum` is optional and the following is valid too:

```dart
extension on num {}
```

When you use your extension in another file, you **must** give it a name.

---

The extension above will make use of [implicit extension member invocations](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.7/static-extension-methods/feature-specification.md#implicit-extension-member-invocation) as you do not have to explicitly declare your `num` to be a `FancyNum`.

You can also explicitly declare your extension, but this is not needed in most cases:

```dart
print(FancyNum(1).plus(2));
```

### Flex childCount

The desired behavior from the question can be achieved by extending `Row` or `Column`, or even better: you can extend [`Flex`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html), which is the super class of `Row` *and* `Column`:

```dart
extension ExtendedFlex on Flex {
  int get childCount => this.children.length;
}
```

`this.` can also be omitted if `children` is not defined in the current lexical scope of `childCount`, which means that `=> children.length` is also valid.

---

With this *static extension* of `Flex` imported, you can call it on any `Flex`, i.e. also on every `Row` and `Column`.
`Row(children: const [Text('one'), Text('two')]).childCount` will evaluate to `2`.

Comment: this line "When you use your extension in another file, you must give it a name." thank you

Comment: Does this require manual import of extension file ?

Comment: yes, you should give extension function a name but you can use it another class without that name

Answer (score 18):

Dart 2.7 introduced new Extension Method concept.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

```
extension ParseNumbers on String {
    int parseInt() {
        return int.parse(this);
    }
    double parseDouble() {
        return double.parse(this);
    }
}
main() {
    int i = '42'.parseInt();
    print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do following for dart extension functions:

**Define an extension:**

```
extension MyString on String {
  void addPrefix(String prefix){
   print('$prefix $this');
  }
}
```

**Use the extension:**

```
void main(){
  String message = 'Hello, World!';
  message.addPrefix('Message:'); // Output: Message: Hello, World!

}
```