# Extracting Class Members like Widget Builders to a Different File?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In developing some of the screens for my flutter app, I regularly need to dynamically render widgets based on the state of the screen. For circumstances where it makes sense to create a separate widget and include it, I do that.

However, there are many use cases where what I need to render is not fit for a widget, and leverages existing state from the page. Therefore I use builder methods to render the appropriate widgets to the page. As anyone who uses Flutter knows, that can lead to lengthy code where you need to scroll up/down a lot to get to what you need to work on.

For better maintainability, I would love to move those builder methods into separate files, and then just include them. This would make it much easier to work on specific code widgets rendered and make the screen widget much cleaner.

But I haven't found a proper way to extract that dynamic widget code, which makes use of state, calls to update state, etc. I'm looking for a type of "include" file that would insert code into the main screen and render as if it's part of the core code.

Is this possible? How to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [introduction of `extension` members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751), I came across this really neat way of achieving exactly what your described!

Say you have a `State` class defined like this:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int cakes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    cakes = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) => Text('$cakes'),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is a local variable `cakes` and a `builder` function. The very neat way to extract this builder now is the following:

```dart
extension CakesBuilderExtension on MyWidgetState {
  Widget cakesBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('$cakes');
  }
}
```

Now, the `cakes` member can be accessed from the `extension` even if the extension is placed in another file.

Now, you would update your `State` class like this (the `builder` changed):

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int cakes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    cakes = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: cakesBuilder,
    );
  }
}
```

The `cakesBuilder` can be referenced from `MyWidgetState`, even though it is only declared in the `CakesBuilderExtension`!

### Note

The `extension` feature requires *Dart 2.6*. This is not yet available in the stable channel, but should be around the end of 2019 I guess. Thus, you need to use the `dev` or `master` channels: `flutter channel dev` or `flutter channel master` and update the `environment` constraint in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.6.0-dev.8.2 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. I'm pretty set on using the stable branch, so I'll wait till this is included in the coming release. By end of 2019 would be great.