# How do you combine Colors as if one was Painted onto the other?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to basically add two colors together as if I were to do the following with a [`Canvas`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) object:

```dart
canvas.drawPaint(Paint()..color = colorB);
canvas.drawPaint(Paint()..color = colorA);
```

Essentially, I have a background color `colorA` and another color `colorB`. I want to get a **`combinedColor`** that would be the result from painting `colorA` onto `colorB` but *without using the canvas*.

I tried the following, but it is not implemented:

```dart
final combinedColor = colorA + colorB;
```

For example, if I have a semi-transparent `colorA` and another color that I want to paint `colorA` on, the other color should act as a background, i.e. as if it had full opacity itself - basically the way you would expect.

How do I add together colors like this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I happened to find a method for this in the [`Color` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html):

### `Color.alphaBlend`

```dart
final colorC = Color.alphaBlend(colorA, colorB);
```

[`alphaBlend`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/alphaBlend.html) allows you to combine two colors, where the *first* parameter is the **foreground** color and the *second* is the **background** color. So here, `colorA` is the foreground and `colorB` the background color.

### `operator +`

The code sample from the question can be made working by [creating an `extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751):

```dart
extension on Color {
  Color operator +(Color other) => Color.alphaBlend(this, other);
}
```

Now, the following code will work:

```dart
final combinedColor = colorA + addendColor;
```

Note that the way I created the extension, the addend (here `addendColor`) will be the **background**. You can change this by reversing `(this, other)` to `(other, this)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the resulting color is not a constant expression. I get the error `In constant expressions, operands of this operator must be of type 'num'.`

Comment: @Brendan Of course, `alphaBlend` is a method and therefore not `const`.