# Implementing Multiple Pages into a Single Page using Navigation and a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hooks

In Flutter, I want to make screens like with `Fragment` in android, in this my code i try to replace each screens into current screen like with `Fragment.replecae` in android, i used `Hook` and `Provider` and my code work fine when in click on buttons to switch between them but i can't implementing back stack, which means when i click on `Back` button on phone, my code should show latest screen which i stored into `_backStack` variable, each swtich between this screens i stored current screen index into the this variable.

how can i solve back from this stack in my sample code?

```
// Switch Between screens:
DashboardPage(), UserProfilePage(), SearchPage()
------------->   ------------->     ------------->
```

```
// When back from stack:
                      DashboardPage(), UserProfilePage(), SearchPage()
Exit from application <--------------  <----------------  <-----------
```

i used `Hook` and i want to implementing this action with this library features

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    Provider.value(value: StreamBackStackSupport()),
    StreamProvider<homePages>(
      create: (context) =>
          Provider.of<StreamBackStackSupport>(context, listen: false)
              .selectedPage,
    )
  ], child: StartupApplication()));
}

class StartupApplication extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BackStack Support App',
      home: MainBodyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MainBodyApp extends HookWidget {
  final List<Widget> _fragments = [
    DashboardPage(),
    UserProfilePage(),
    SearchPage()
  ];
  List<int> _backStack = [0];
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BackStack Screen'),
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(
        // ignore: missing_return
        onWillPop: () {
          customPop(context);
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Consumer<homePages>(
                builder: (context, selectedPage, child) {
                  _currentIndex = selectedPage != null ? selectedPage.index : 0;
                  _backStack.add(_currentIndex);
                  return Expanded(child: _fragments[_currentIndex]);
                },
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                color: Colors.indigo[400],
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => Provider.of<StreamBackStackSupport>(
                              context,
                              listen: false)
                          .switchBetweenPages(homePages.screenDashboard),
                      child: Text('Dashboard'),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => Provider.of<StreamBackStackSupport>(
                              context,
                              listen: false)
                          .switchBetweenPages(homePages.screenProfile),
                      child: Text('Profile'),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => Provider.of<StreamBackStackSupport>(
                              context,
                              listen: false)
                          .switchBetweenPages(homePages.screenSearch),
                      child: Text('Search'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigateBack(int index) {
    useState(() => _currentIndex = index);
  }

  void customPop(BuildContext context) {
    if (_backStack.length - 1 > 0) {
      navigateBack(_backStack[_backStack.length - 1]);
    } else {
      _backStack.removeAt(_backStack.length - 1);
      Provider.of<StreamBackStackSupport>(context, listen: false)
          .switchBetweenPages(homePages.values[_backStack.length - 1]);
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}

class UserProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(' screenProfile ...'),
    );
  }
}

class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(' screenDashboard ...'),
    );
  }
}

class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(' screenSearch ...'),
    );
  }
}

enum homePages { screenDashboard, screenProfile, screenSearch }

class StreamBackStackSupport {
  final StreamController<homePages> _homePages = StreamController<homePages>();

  Stream<homePages> get selectedPage => _homePages.stream;

  void switchBetweenPages(homePages selectedPage) {
    _homePages.add(homePages.values[selectedPage.index]);
  }

  void close() {
    _homePages.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### TL;DR

The full code is at the end.

### Use `Navigator` instead

You should approach this problem differently. I could present you with a solution that would work with your approach, however, I think that you should instead solve this by implementing a *custom [`Navigator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)* as this is a built-in solution in Flutter.

---

When you are using a `Navigator`, you do not need any of your stream-based management, i.e. you can remove `StreamBackStackSupport` entirely.

Now, you insert a `Navigator` widget where you had your `Consumer` before:

```dart
children: <Widget>[
  Expanded(
    child: Navigator(
      ...
    ),
  ),
  Container(...), // Your bottom bar..
]
```

The navigator manages its routes using strings, which means that we will need to have a way to convert your `enum` (which I renamed to `Page`) to `String`s. We can use [`describeEnum`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html) for that and put that into an [`extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751):

```dart
enum Page { screenDashboard, screenProfile, screenSearch }

extension on Page {
  String get route => describeEnum(this);
}
```

Now, you can get the string representation of a page using e.g. `Page.screenDashboard.route`.

Furthermore, you want to map your actual pages to your fragment widgets, which you can do like this:

```dart
class MainBodyApp extends HookWidget {
  final Map<Page, Widget> _fragments = {
    Page.screenDashboard: DashboardPage(),
    Page.screenProfile: UserProfilePage(),
    Page.screenSearch: SearchPage(),
  };
  ...
```

To access the `Navigator`, we need to have a [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html). Usually we would have a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and manage the `GlobalKey` like that. Since you want to use `flutter_hooks`, I opted to use a [`GlobalObjectKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalObjectKey-class.html) instead:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final navigatorKey = GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState>(context);
  ...
```

Now, you can use `navigatorKey.currentState` anywhere in your widget to access this custom navigator. The full `Navigator` setup looks like this:

```dart
Navigator(
  key: navigatorKey,
  initialRoute: Page.screenDashboard.route,
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    final pageName = settings.name;

    final page = _fragments.keys.firstWhere((element) => describeEnum(element) == pageName);

    return MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: (context) => _fragments[page]);
  },
)
```

As you can see, we pass the `navigatorKey` created before and define an `initialRoute`, making use of the `route` extension we created. In `onGenerateRoute`, we find the `Page` enum entry corresponding to the route name (a `String`) and then return a `MaterialPageRoute` with the appropriate `_fragments` entry.

To push a new route, you simply use the `navigatorKey` and [`pushNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushNamed.html):

```dart
onPressed: () => navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(Page.screenDashboard.route),
```

### Back button

We also need to customly call [`pop`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pop.html) on our custom navigator. For this purpose, a [`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) is needed:

```dart
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    if (navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
      navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  },
  child: ..,
)
```

### Access the custom navigator inside of the nested pages

In any page that is passed to `onGenerateRoute`, i.e. in any of your "fragments", you can just call `Navigator.of(context)` instead of using the global key. This is possible because these routes are children of the custom navigator and thus, the `BuildContext` contains that custom navigator.

For example:

```dart
// In SearchPage
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Page.screenProfile.route);
```

#### Default navigator

You might be wondering how you can get access to the `MaterialApp` root navigator now, e.g. to push a new full screen route. You can use [`findRootAncestorStateOfType`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findRootAncestorStateOfType.html) for that:

```dart
context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>().push(..);
```

or simply

```dart
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(..);
```

---

Here is the full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(StartupApplication());
}

enum Page { screenDashboard, screenProfile, screenSearch }

extension on Page {
  String get route => describeEnum(this);
}

class StartupApplication extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BackStack Support App',
      home: MainBodyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MainBodyApp extends HookWidget {
  final Map<Page, Widget> _fragments = {
    Page.screenDashboard: DashboardPage(),
    Page.screenProfile: UserProfilePage(),
    Page.screenSearch: SearchPage(),
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final navigatorKey = GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState>(context);

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
          navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('BackStack Screen'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Navigator(
                  key: navigatorKey,
                  initialRoute: Page.screenDashboard.route,
                  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                    final pageName = settings.name;

                    final page = _fragments.keys.firstWhere(
                        (element) => describeEnum(element) == pageName);

                    return MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings,
                        builder: (context) => _fragments[page]);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                color: Colors.indigo[400],
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => navigatorKey.currentState
                          .pushNamed(Page.screenDashboard.route),
                      child: Text('Dashboard'),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => navigatorKey.currentState
                          .pushNamed(Page.screenProfile.route),
                      child: Text('Profile'),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => navigatorKey.currentState
                          .pushNamed(Page.screenSearch.route),
                      child: Text('Search'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(' screenProfile ...'),
    );
  }
}

class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(' screenDashboard ...'),
    );
  }
}

class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(' screenSearch ...'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Now how can I use `navigatorKey.currentState .pushNamed(Page.screenDashboard.route)` in nested pages? For example `SearchPage` ? I used `Provider` for this action

Comment: @DolDurma Sorry, I forgot to mention. In any page that is controlled by your custom navigator, you can use `Navigator.of(context)` because that `BuildContext` contains the custom navigator. I edited the answer to include this. Glad I was able to help you.

Comment: Could you update your your post for helping anybody want to use this solution? Thanks

Comment: @DolDurma Yes! I did that (: See the "Acces the custom navigator inside of the nested pages" section.

Comment: your code and your solution is what i want to have, thanks a lot. i have some question. how can i avoid navigate multiple the same pages? for example when i on dashboard page clicking any other button should be couldn't navigate again and my another question is can i have multiple nested this navigation strategy? for example dashboard page can be have another this navigation, like with instagram

Comment: and when i separate `extension` to another file `extension RouteExtensions on Page {
  String get route => describeEnum(this);
}` route doesn't work for me `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Page.screenProfile.route);` and i get this error: `Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("screenProfile", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.`

Comment: @DolDurma If you want to use the extension in another file, you have to give it a name, like `extension PageExtension on Page {}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210632/discussion-between-doldurma-and-creativecreatorormaybenot).

Comment: Now this is what I call a "Quality Answer", great job, you deserve 200 :) However, there is a mistake, It should be `findRootAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()` and then there is a freeze in exiting application.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thanks for the edit (: I try to do my best - you learned a lot as well over time.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Thanks sir for your compliment, I knew something like that is gonna come, however I am still having issues in exiting the app (`SystemNavigator` seems to work) but these two fail, any other solution?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Yes, you are right. I was sloppy in that part of my answer. I am not sure why I named that example as this is obviously not how the last route of the navigator works (I said exit the app but meant pop the last route, which you would not want to do). I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @ i used `get_it` to share `navigatorKey` whole application for example: `class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}` and when i use  `if (ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name != Page.screenSearch) ` i get `/` always

Comment: @DolDurma Yes, of course. Make sure to pass `settings` in `onGenerateRoute` and then, sorry again. The `navigatorKey` context does obviously not include the correct route settings, only the children of the custom navigator. This means that you need the context of your pages, which is not that easy to obtain. I would instead create a global variable that saves what the current screen is (you do not need to maintain a stack as only the current one matters). So if you want to share it throughout your whole app, store a `Page` global variable with the current page and update that in `onPressed`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot do you know why i get this error: `Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("screenProfile", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
` in our main project

Comment: @DolDurma This probably means that you have either not specified `onGenerateRoute` in your custom navigator *or* you are *not using* your custom navigator and instead the `MaterialApp` navigator. This happens when the `context` does not contain your custom navigator, e.g. when you call `Navigator.of(context)` in your `MainBodyApp`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot problem is when i try to separate classes to another files i can't use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(...)` or `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).` or `context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>().push(..);` [GITHUB link](https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/nested-page-sampl), the source of your implementation

Comment: @DolDurma You need to pass your `navigatorKey` to your `TestBottomBar`, i.e. as a parameter. Then you can use `navigatorKey.currentState` in your `TestBottomBar` again.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot this is not good idea, because of i have more that 10 pages in whole application which i want to use this feature

Comment: @DolDurma In the pages you can use `Navigator.of(context)` (when they are children of the custom navigator). In other widgets, such as the bottom bar, you will have to pass the global key.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot let me to check that by DI

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I'm not sure completely, but i think this problem solved by DI

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot i awarded bounty you Thanks

Comment: how do I use pushReplacement instead of pushNamed, since i don't want when I push the back button, it back to the same page?

Comment: @DolDuma: Nicely done. In your answer you said "You should approach this problem differently.".

Can I bother you to share the other approach? I am guessing that approach doesn't require Flutter_Hooks?

Comment: Nice answer, however getting an issue where `builder: (context) => _fragments[page])` has a compilation error due `The return type 'Widget?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context`. Thoughts?