# How to use extension methods in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to understand how to use extension methods in dart/flutter.

the extension

```
extension on Text {
  Text get boldCardTitle {
    
    return Text(this.data!, style:const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500) );
  }
  
}
```

I am trying to do something like this, and have it inherit those styles

```
Text('5401 Odom Ave \nFort Worth, TX 76114').boldCardTitle,
```

Comment: follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288235/how-do-i-use-dart-extension-functions

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. What's the problem?

Comment: without naming the extension i am getting this error `The getter 'boldCardTitle' isn't defined for the type 'Text'.
Try importing the library that defines 'boldCardTitle', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'boldCardTitle'.` which is what I was asking about in the answer below @Lebecca

Comment: Import the extension file

Comment: your code is correct,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a name for the extension:

```
extension TextExtension on Text {
  ...
}
```

Comment: can I just ask why a name if I don't have to call the name?

Comment: An extension is like a subclass. When you extends a class you must give a name to the subclass.